# QML newbie needing help accessing Item properties from within C++

Tags: qt, qt4, qml, qt-quick

I am developing an application in QT and QML to access some XML data and display the results.

The XML is downloaded / parsed from C++ and this works fine.
I have a QML application designed to display the custom layout and that also works fine.

To make the app look more polished I have an initial "splash screen" that's displayed whilst the C++ side completes the initial download / parse, I have created a property inside the main QML view to represent the current application "state" so I can swap to the correct screen when the data is ready.

**Main.qml**

```
Item
{
   id: mainScreen
   width: 800; height: 600;   
   property int activeState: 0       // This controls what screen is displayed

   Item 
   {
       // screen layout .. removed .. 
   }
}
```

The C++ code is generated by the QT creator app wizard and is based around the basic `QmlApplicationViewer` class.

I've read (and re-read) the online QT docs and supposedly all I have to do to access the individual properties of `mainScreen` is to call the `findChild<QObject *>` method of the application viewers `rootContext()` to return a `QObject` pointer to the `mainScreen` instance and then call the `setProperty` method like so.

```
QObject *mainView = ROOT_CONTEXT->findChild<QObject *>("mainScreen");

qDebug("mainView = %08X",(uint)mainView);

if(mainView)
{
    mainView->setProperty("activeState",1);
}
else
    qDebug("Unable to find the mainScreen QML object");
```

Where `ROOT_CONTEXT` is defined elsewhere as

```
QDeclarativeContext *ROOT_CONTEXT;
QDeclarativeEngine  *ROOT_ENGINE;
QGraphicsObject     *ROOT_OBJECT;

void QmlApplicationViewer::createMyApplication(void)
{
    ROOT_CONTEXT = this->rootContext();
    ROOT_OBJECT  = this->rootObject();
    ROOT_ENGINE  = this->engine();

    pMyApplication = new MyApplication(this);
}
```

and `void QmlApplicationViewer::createMyApplication(void)` is called after the main QML file has been setup ie

```
QmlApplicationViewer viewer;

viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("main.qml"));
viewer.showExpanded();
viewer.createMyApplication();
```

BUT...

The problem I'm running into is that that the value returned from `findChild<QObject *>("mainScreen");` is always NULL.  I've tried enumerating through the hierarchy of objects in my QML file using the following code

```
QList<QObject*> list = ROOT_OBJECT->findChildren<QObject*>();

qDebug("list = %d",list.count());
int i;

for(i=0;i<list.count();i++)
{
    QObject *obj = list[i];

    qDebug() << "Object" << i << obj->objectName();
}
```

and I get a list of ~120 items but they all have a blank string ("") for their name.

Looking back at the QT docs all the examples seem to suggest creating the individual parts by hand (ie creating an instance of `QDeclarativeEngine`, `QDeclarativeComponent` and `QDeclarativeItem`) and linking them together instead of using the `QApplicationViewer` class as shown on this blog entry http://xizhizhu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/hybrid-application-using-qml-and-qt-c.html, but I'd much rather stick with the code I've already written.

Can anyone please help and suggest where I'm going wrong or point me in the direction where I can find a "simple" example of being able to change a property of an Item in a QML file from C++.

Many (many) thanks in advance.

Jon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main.qml should be**

```
Item
{
   id: mainScreen
   objectName: "mainScreen"
   width: 800; height: 600;   
   property int activeState: 0       // This controls what screen is displayed

   Item 
   {
       // screen layout .. removed .. 
   }
}
```

You were missing the objectName: "mainScreen", that's how findChild<>() finds it's children.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I can see how I'd need that property (I'd missed that section of the docs - looking back again I can see the property listed in the example QML files).  However I'm still getting NULL, I'll have to go back and carefully work through the code to make sure I haven't missed anything else.   FWIW - I was trying to access the root Item I wonder if it'll work if I try and access an element that's a child of the root item?  Thanks again for your help. 8-)

Comment: @Techdojo If the answer is good for you, you should accept it. Take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Accepted - please see note below!

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

The following code

```
QList<QObject*> list = ROOT_OBJECT->findChildren<QObject*>();

qDebug("list = %d",list.count());
int i;

for(i=0;i<list.count();i++)
{
    QObject *obj = list[i];
    qDebug() << "Object" << i << obj->objectName();
}
```

Works and dumps out the list of objects and when I use the objectName: property in my QML files as mentioned above I can see (and access) the children of the ROOT Item in my application.

What I can't seem to do however is actually access the ACTUAL ROOT item and set it's properties - it them dawned on me in a typical face palm moment that I ALREADY HAD A REFERENCE TO THE ROOT OBJECT!  It's was the value already stored in the ROOT_OBJECT variable * *sheesh* *

So in summary...

All of the above code works - to actually find and adjust the properties of a CHILD off the main view, remember to set the **`objectName:`**, if you want to actually change a property IN the root item - just use the value returned by the **`QDeclaritiveView::rootObject()`** function.

Thanks again to **IvanFel** for pointing me in the right direction, Hopefully this will show up in a search sometime and help someone else in the same way that a lot of stackOverflow entries have helped me in the past.

8-)